# How to connect a computer with something like a little electric car?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am a complete beginner and I wondered how to hardware like a controller with a f.e. little electric car. So when I want to program a controller like a ps4 controller so that it can let a little electric car drive, how can I do that? (programming language in best case Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi is a popular single-board computer that can be programmed to achieve this. Somebody actually already built one full-sized electric car, called the [Teslonda](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/teslonda-tesla-honda-powered-raspberry-pi).

If you want to go smaller than the Raspberry Pi Zero, you can try programming an Arduino (but this involves C instead of Python).

Both the Raspberry Pi and Arduino has their own Stack Exchange sites. You might get a better response there than here.

Comment: is there a youtube tutorial series that you can recommend?

Comment: Here's a nice one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41IO4Qe5Jzw